# How do I see the size of the bootstrap grid size on my page while developing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

While developing a web page it would be handy to see which sets of size classes are active: xs, sm, md, lg.

I've noted that there are some extensions that show the grid overlay, but not the size.

Is there a way to indicate which size sets are active?

Comment: Bootstrap grid system has 4 classes `xs` for mobile, `sm` for tablets, `md` for desktops, and `lg` for larger desktops.

Answer (score 11):

With bootstrap 4.1 you can add something like this on your page.

The code below will show what is the current class used by bootstrap based on your screen width.

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <div class="d-none d-xl-block font-weight-bold">X-LARGE (XL)</div>
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none font-weight-bold">LARGE (LG)</div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none font-weight-bold">MEDIUM (M)</div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none font-weight-bold">SMALL (SM)</div>
    <div class="d-block d-sm-none alert font-weight-bold">X-SMALL (Defaut)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check your screen sizes or media queries break points through Developer Tools like on Google Chrome. You can check "[Test Responsive and Device-specific Viewports](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports)" from Google Chromes Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap grid system has 4 classes

1. xs for mobile (Below 768px)
2. sm for tablets (Above 768 and Below 992)
3. md for desktops (Above 992 and Below 1200)
4. lg for larger desktops (Above 1200)

So, with this values. You can change the width and understand the class currently active now.

Comment: I understand that.  I just want a visual indicator to tell me the size set as I am resizing the browser.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any extention if you are using developer tools of chrome.

1. Just open Chrome developer tools by pressing F12
2. Resize window
3. You will see size of window at top-right corner.
4. Select Div in developer window for which you want to check which class is Active.
5. Resize window again.
6. you will see active class name will be visible in Styles pane of developer tools.
   [image: Screen shot of developer tools]

Answer (score 1):

There is javascript solution :

[Responsive Bootstrap Toolkit](https://github.com/maciej-gurban/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit)

If you want to detect current size set with css, you can create a css rule for body or any other element like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .body-helper {background: green;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1279px) {
    .body-helper {background: pink;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .body-helper {background: maroon;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .body-helper {background: lightblue;}
}
```

Please use appropriate breakpoints of your bootstrap settings. So you can identify current size set with background change.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with hidden columns. So you hidde a div in other screen-sizes.

**Example:**

```
 <div class="col-lg-3"> <div class="visible-lg hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">col-lg</div> </div>
```

**Learn more:** [Scotch.io](https://www.google.de/amp/scotch.io/amp/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system) - Responsive Utilities

Answer (score 0):

I used a method that might be silly, but it works great.

You can do something like this, which will show the size on screen, but since the size is 0 then it's going to hide it. (don't use visibility hidden 'cause it doesn't work)

```html
<span id="theSize" style="font-size: 0;">
  <span class="d-none d-lg-block">LG</span>
  <span class="d-none d-md-block d-lg-none">MD</span>
  <!-- and the rest of the sizes -->
</span>
```

and this is the code for checking the size in javascript.

```js
if (document.getElementById('theSize').innerText == 'LG') //large
  // do something
else if (document.getElementById('theSize').innerText == 'MD') //medium
  // do another thing.

// for the rest of the sizes
else if ...
else if ...
else ...
```